# Make the link to Stack Exchange Data Explorer Tutorial more visible

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

Can you display the link to the SEDE tutorial in a more prominent fashion please?

Currently, it seems buried in the text of [the help page](https://data.stackexchange.com/help).

Perhaps at the bottom of ["new query" page](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new)?

Comment: Trello card: https://trello.com/c/ofvzZDrH/1-reconfigure-help-link-in-topbar-to-have-reference-doc-current-help-and-tutorial-entries